# C++ - Getting Byte from Console

Tags: c++, char, byte, cin

I am new to C++ and coming from a C# / Java background I feel like I am kind of spoilt.

What I am trying to achieve here is to get the data input by the user as byte (`unsigned char`) using `cin`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char byte;

int main()
{
    byte num = 0;
    char exitKey = '0';

    cout << "Type in a number between 0 and 255.\n";
    cin >> num;

    cout << "\nYour number multiplied by 2 is:\n" << (num * 2);
    cin >> exitKey;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Example]

The value returned is the ASCII decimal value of the character I typed in. How can I get the actual value, treating the value as a number?

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use the int or short datatype instead of char.

Comment: can you use fread on stdin?

Comment: I would suggest using `fread`.try using this debug statement: `printf("%d\n","1");` maybe it is 49. It seems like you read the character '1' not the number '1'.

Comment: @LittleByBlue That `printf` call will most likely *not* print `49`, but something complete different (and longer), as it will print the address of the string literal `"1"`. Also, why use `fread` or other old C functions in a C++ program?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it is `printf("%d\n",'1');` of course. ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter what type-aliases you use, when reading using `cin >>` a character is always a character, and will be read as a character.

The value you are getting is the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) code for the character `'1'`.

If you want to read it as a number, then use a proper numeric datatype, like `int`.

Comment: In terms of program efficiency, will `unsigned short int` be as efficient as `byte`, since `short` takes up more memory space than 256?

Comment: @IsaacHili Using `int`, `short` or even `long long` (or their `unsigned` variants) will not make any measurable impact on most modern PC-type systems. Maybe if you need to read a few hundred million numbers it might be measurable, but hardly even then it might be worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using char datatype here. The 1 value entered here is considered as character and ASCII value of 1 (49) is getting stored and 49 * 2 = 98 is getting printed.
Instead of char use int as datatype.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)